# How to pass an null object using Bundle

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, uri, bundle

I'm using bundle to send an image uri from an activity to a fragment.

The problem is that the user might choose not to use an image an by then I'll have an empty string which will give me this error:

**Activity:**

```
private Uri mainImageUri = null;

// Image Crop 

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            mainImageUri = result.getUri();
            profilePic.setImageURI(mainImageUri);

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}

// OnCreateView

String profilePicUri = mainImageUri.toString();

// OnClickListener

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("USER_PIC_URI", profilePicUri);
                            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            //fragmentTransaction...etc
```

**Fragment**

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    final String profilePicUri = bundle.getString("USER_PIC_URI");
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
```

I tried this but without luck

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            if (mainImageUri != null) {
                            bundle.putString("USER_PIC_URI", profilePicUri);
                            } else {
                            bundle.putString("USER_PIC_URI", "");
                            }
                            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

How can I implement an if statement to handle the NullPointerException created by the user who doesn't want to upload a picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not that the string is empty, it is that the uri is null so you cannot call `uri.toString()` on it.

One solution would be to check for a null uri when you bundle it (so don't call `mainImageUri.toString()` where you currently are, remove `profilePicUri` completely) and only attempt to convert it to a string if it is non-null

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if (mainImageUri != null) {
    bundle.putString("USER_PIC_URI", mainImageUri.toString());
} else {
    bundle.putString("USER_PIC_URI", "");
}
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Your error is coming from this line when `mainImageUri` is null

```
String profilePicUri = mainImageUri.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String profilePicUri = null;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            mainImageUri = result.getUri();
            profilePic.setImageURI(mainImageUri);
            profilePicUri = mainImageUri.toString();

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}
```

profilePicUri should be **global** variable. And you shouldn't initiliaze it in onCreate method you should initiliaze it in **onActivityResult** method.